# How to declare the array type in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, types, return

So in a swift playground file, I am trying to execute the following closure:

```
var list = [5, 4, 3]

var Arraymultiplier = {(list:Array) -> Array in 
    for value in list {
        value*2
        return list
    }
}

Arraymultiplier(list)
```

When I do this though, I get an error saying that the generic type Array must be referenced in <..> brackets, but when I put the brackets, I get another error.

What's the right way to declare the array type as an input and a return?

Comment: Can you show how you tried solving the "must be referenced in <..> brackets" error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array` is a [generic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179) type, meaning that it expects to see the actual type of the members of the array to be specified within `<` `>` immediately following `Array`:

```
var arrayMultiplier = {(list: Array<Int>) -> Array<Int> in 
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

Or, in the case of arrays, there is a convenient syntax that uses the `[` `]` characters and omits the need for `Array` reference at all:

```
var arrayMultiplier = {(list: [Int]) -> [Int] in 
    // do whatever you want here
}
```

---

I'm not sure what the original code sample was trying to do, but it looks like you might have been trying to build a new array with each item multiplied by 2. If so, then you might do something like:

```
let inputList = [5, 4, 3]

let arrayMultiplier = { (list: [Int]) -> [Int] in 
    var results = [Int]()                         // instantiate a new blank array of `Int`
    for value in list {                           // iterate through array passed to us
        results.append(value * 2)                 // multiply each `value` by `2` and add it to the `results`
    }
    return results                                // return results
}

let outputList = arrayMultiplier(inputList)
```

Or, obviously, you could efficiently achieve similar behavior using the `map` function:

```
let outputList = inputList.map { $0 * 2 }
```